# Exception : io.objectbox.exception.DbDetachedException Even though entity is attached

Tags: java, android, database, jackson2, objectbox

Using Jackson with Retrofit, I wanted to have list of friends set to `friendToMany` during Deserialization. As I have gone through with documentation, we have to manually assign that entity to boxstore when `assignable=true` is set. So, I am doing this way(as shown in code). This approach works only for first item which this code is part of. It doesn't work for element 2 or further.

```
@Id(assignable = true)
@JsonProperty("_id")
public long id;

@Transient
private List<Friend> friends = null;

@JsonIgnore
@Backlink(to = "demoResponseToOne")
ToMany<Friend> friendToMany;

@JsonProperty("friends")
public void setFriends(
        List<Friend> friends)
    {
    this.friends = friends;
    for (Friend friend : friends)
        {
        MyApplication.getBoxStore().boxFor(Friend.class).attach(friend);
        friendToMany.add(friend);
        }
    }
```

Exception thrown is : `io.objectbox.exception.DbDetachedException: Cannot resolve relation for detached entities, call box.attach(entity) beforehand.` at the time of `add(friend)`. I mean this works when this Root element is first item of list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the `Box<Friend>` to `this` as well, which owns the `ToMany` to be modified:

```
MyApplication.getBoxStore().boxFor(Friend.class).attach(this);
```

Background: If you are using `@Id(assignable = true)` you need to take care of some things that ObjectBox would normally do for you. This includes attaching the `Box` before modifying any `ToMany`.

Source:
https://docs.objectbox.io/relations#updating-tomany
https://docs.objectbox.io/advanced/object-ids#self-assigned-object-ids